# WPF 2 labels width respond to windows resize

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im trying to make 2 labels to always cover the same percentage of screen size on window resize
That is Label1 50% of Left screen size and Label 2 the other 50% half of screen size

Right now i dont get the desired result. Only one of the 2 resizes by consuming the other label width.

Can anyone help me to get that 50-50 relation?

[image]

On a Grid layout here is the XAML for the 2 labels

```
 <Label Content="Label1" Margin="10,187,603,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" Background="#FF454545" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" />
 <Label Content="Label2" Margin="0,187,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" Background="#FF454545" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="587"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the `column definitions` of the grid and leave away the `margins` of the labels. So the grid automatically handles resizing for you.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" Background="#FF454545" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" Background="#FF454545" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" />
</Grid>
```